# Fixed Point of a Shrinking Map

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Show that if $f : X \to X$ is a shrinking map, where $X$ is a compact metric space, then $f$ has a unique fixed point. [Hint: Let $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^n(X)$. Given $x \in A$, choose $x_n$ so that $x = f^{n+1}(x_n)$. If $a$ is the limit of some subsequence of $y_n = f^n(x_n)$, show that $a \in A$ and $f(a) = x$.]

I realize that this has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612120/fixed-point-of-a-shrinking-map-proof), where Saal Hardali seems to have attempted at working out a proof similar to that suggested by Munkres; but evidently there is a gap in his. I am aware of simpler proofs (in fact, I am came up with simpler proof myself by noting that $g(x) = d(f(x),x)$ is a continuous function and using $X$ compactness), so please don't provide a link to a simpler proof; I want to get Munkres' suggested proof to work. There are a few parts of which I am uncertain

> Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, $f(X)$ is compact. Moreover, $f(X) \subseteq X$ and therefore $f^2(X) \subseteq f(X)$, where $f^2(X)$ is also compact. Through induction, we can show that $f(X) \supseteq f^2(X) \subseteq f^3(X) \supseteq ...$ (i.e., nested sequence), and that $f^n(X)$ is compact for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Moreover, since $X$ is compact Hausdorff, each $f^n(X)$ is closed, and therefore $A := \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^n(X)$ is not empty. It isn't hard to show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^n(X) = \bigcap_{n=m}^\infty f^n(X)$ for every $m \in \Bbb{N}$ (see another one of my MSE posts). Thus, in particular, and since it is not empty, $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^{n}(X) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^{n+1}(X)$ implies there exists an $x_n \in X$ such that $x = f^{n+1}(x_n)$ for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$.
>
> Now consider the the sequence $\{f^n(x_n)\}$. Since $X$ is a compact metric space, it must be also be sequentially compact, meaning there exists a subsequence $f^{n_k}(x_{n_k})$ such that $f^{n_k}(x_{n_k}) \to a$ and therefore by continuity $f^{n_k+1}(x_{n_k}) \to f(a)$, which is a subsequence of $f^{n+1}(x_n)$ (right?); and since $A$ is a closed set containing this convergent sequence, $a \in A$. Uniqueness of limits implies $f(a) = x$.
>
> Now we prove $f(A) = A$. Note that $f(A) = f(\bigcap_{n=1}f^{n}(X)) \subseteq \bigcap_{n=1}f^{n+1}(X) = \bigcap_{n=1}f^{n}(X)$. The other direction is trivial (at least it seemed so...?). Hence $diam(A) = diam(f(A))$. By compactness, there exist there exist $w,z \in A = f(A)$, and therefore $w=f(p)$ and $z=f(q)$ for some $p,q \in A$, such that $diam(A) = d(w,z)$. If $diam(A) > 0$, $w,z$ form a distinct pair, as do $p,q$, and therefore $diam(A) = d(w,z) = d(f(p),f(q)) < d(p,q) \le diam(A)$, a contradiction. Hence $diam(A)=0$ which means $A = \{x\} \ni a$ and therefore $f(x)=x$.

Whew! I am really surprised that Munkres would suggest such a lengthy proof; perhaps I have unnecessary steps in my proof.

Comment: Say... Who is that Munkres'?

Comment: @amsmath Hmm? He is the author of a very well-known topology book

Comment: So why do you refer to him all the time? Do you think everybody here knows that book?

Comment: @amsmath I think it is reasonable to assume that most people are familiar with Munkres' Topology.

Comment: Surely it's not. I am not. I have not even heard of this name before.

Comment: I think your reasoning for $a\in A$ is not correct.

Comment: And why is $A\subset f(A)$ trivial? Actually, you proved the trivial direction. BTW, if you have $f(A) = A$, then $a\in A$ follows immediately. However, I like the end of your proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning for $a\in A$ is false. At least, I don't see what you mean. Here is a valid proof:

Let $m\in\mathbb N$ be arbitrary. We will prove that $a\in f^m(X)$. Then $a\in A$ follows as $m$ was arbitrary. To see this, simply choose a convergent subsequence $(f^{n_{k_j}-m}(x_{n_{k_j}}))_j$ of $(f^{n_k-m}(x_{n_k}))_k$. Let its limit be $b$. Then
$$
a = \lim_j y_{n_{k_j}} = \lim_j f^{m}(f^{n_{k_j}-m}(x_{n_{k_j}})) = f^m(b).
$$
This actually proves $A\subset f(A)$, since we started with some $x\in A$ and proved that $x = f(a)$ with some $a\in A$, i.e., $x\in f(A)$. Hence, $f(A) = A$. Now, you can apply your nice diameter argument to infer that $A$ is a singleton. I guess the proof for the fact that the element in $A$ must be a (unique) fixed point of $f$ is clear to you.

Comment: Really? My proof of $a \in A$ is false? And to think, I was more concerned about whether $f^{n_k+1}(x_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $f^{n+1}(x_{n})$ (which is obvious to me now). I am having trouble seeing why it is false. Certainly $\{f^{n_k}(x_{n_k})\}$ is a sequence of points in the closed set $A$; and since the sequence converges to $a$, it must be in $A$. Can you spot exactly where I go wrong? I can't find my error.

Comment: @user193319 I think you should think about your "certainly"... To make it clear to you: Why should $f^{n_1}(x_{n_1})$ be in $A$?

Comment: Oh...Right! $A$ is the intersection of a bunch of sets. Hmm...I don't think there is any way of fixing that part. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I have another question.What was the point choosing $x = f^{n+1}(x_n)$, as opposed to $x = f^n(x_n)$, given that my way of showing $a \in A$ doesn't work?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you choose $x = f^n(x_n)$, then you would define $y_n = f^{n-1}(x_n)$, $n\ge 2$. There is no difference.